# Converting list of string to string variable doesn't retain the order of elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab

I have an a `list of strings` like `["a", "b"]`. When I convert it to the string variable separated by `", "` it works fine when I test the test cases on the local machine via `debugging` and `tox`. It doesn't work fine in the pipeline once I commit the code on `GitLab`. The order of elements gets reversed. Sometimes it is retained and sometimes not.
I am using the below code to convert it to a string variable:

```
drop_account_names = ", ".join(drop for drop in set(to_drop))
```

The output on my local machine when tested via tox and debugging of tests is correct i.e `'a', 'b'`

However, on the Gitlab pipeline, I get it as `'b', 'a'` sometimes. Why is it so?

Comment: A `set` is not a `list`. And a `set` is unordered [by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: try drop_account_names = ", ".join(drop for drop in list(set(to_drop))) and if is not enough sort the list

Comment: use the list instead of set

Comment: @minattosama your suggestion still includes the `set` and thus order is not guaranteed.

Comment: I think he needs a set to drop the duplicates, but you need to come to a list and order them if needed. @Grismar sort values can be added if needed. I think the set is still needed to drop duplicates

Comment: @minattosama This is just a sample. I think sorting the list explicitly will increase the time complexity. Looking for a better solution. Also `to_drop` is already a list then why should I convert like `list(to_drop)` while converting to string is not clear to me.

Comment: I suggest to put in the request your objectives, if you want to sort or to keep the initial way of sorting. Remember also when using set, the duplicates are automatically dropped. What is your final objective for the function?

Comment: Retain the order is the final objective after converting it to variable of strings

Answer (score 0):

`set`s are unordered, so you will get different results every time. You can use `dict` to retain the order

```
to_drop = ["a", "b", "a"]
to_drop = dict.fromkeys(to_drop)
drop_account_names = ", ".join(to_drop)
print(drop_account_names) # a, b
```

Comment: It fails in the GitLab pipeline.

Comment: @RushHour What is the error?

Comment: The order is reversed in `GitLab`. If I use `sorted(list)` then it works fine but here I am adding an extra time complexity for sorting.

Comment: @RushHour what is the Python version? this will work from Python 3.6

Comment: I am using `3.8`

Comment: @RushHour are you trying to maintain the order of the list or to sort it?

Comment: I want that if the list comes like `['a','b']` and when I create a variable it should be like `var='a', 'b'`